# the callback not triggered in the minifilter

Tags: c++, windows, driver, wdk

I ran into such a problem, a callback is registered in my minifilter here is its prototype:

```cpp
FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS DelProtectPreSetInformation(

    _Inout_ PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data,

    _In_ PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects,

    _Flt_CompletionContext_Outptr_ PVOID* CompletionContext);|
```

here it writes to the callback array:

```cpp
CONST FLT_OPERATION_REGISTRATION Callbacks[] = {

    { IRP_MJ_CREATE, 0, DelProtectPreCreate, nullptr},

    { IRP_MJ_SET_INFORMATION, 0, DelProtectPreSetInformation, nullptr },

    { IRP_MJ_OPERATION_END }

};
```

But when my driver is running this callback just isn't called

Comment: and I was stupid, my function definition returned _FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS